# Manipulating data from a file list array within mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database that contains details on audio books and the file location for the books.  The filelocation can be a multiple file upload.  This is working and does exactly what is expected.

The issue I am having is that now the user would like to export the contents of the database to XML for use in another application.  This is where the problem lies.

Database example:

```
FieldName: BookTitle<br />
Content: War of the Worlds<br />
FieldName: Author<br />
Content: H G Wells<br />
FieldName: FileLocation<br />
Content:[{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch04_wells_64kb_wqd92auj.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch04_wells_64kb.mp3","size":5270144,"type":"audio\/mp3","searchStr":"warofworlds_b2_ch04_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch06_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch05_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch10_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch09_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch08_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch01_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch02_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch03_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch04_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch06_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch05_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch08_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch10_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch07_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch09_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch07_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch11_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch13_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch14_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch12_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch16_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch15_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b1_ch17_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch01_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch03_wells_64kb.mp3,!warofworlds_b2_ch02_wells_64kb.mp3,!:sStrEnd"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch06_wells_64kb_m7j4eow4.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch06_wells_64kb.mp3","size":4134464,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch05_wells_64kb_dqkhae74.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch05_wells_64kb.mp3","size":3274304,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch10_wells_64kb_39ois1bc.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch10_wells_64kb.mp3","size":4315904,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch09_wells_64kb_fjgjexg9.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch09_wells_64kb.mp3","size":5699840,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch08_wells_64kb_v5hckthv.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch08_wells_64kb.mp3","size":9816704,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch01_wells_64kb_h0nml30w.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch01_wells_64kb.mp3","size":7520384,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch02_wells_64kb_woll8288.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch02_wells_64kb.mp3","size":4536704,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch03_wells_64kb_vbzl27ng.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch03_wells_64kb.mp3","size":3336320,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch04_wells_64kb_fdybmn8a.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch04_wells_64kb.mp3","size":3833600,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch06_wells_64kb_iavsdbqx.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch06_wells_64kb.mp3","size":2855936,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch05_wells_64kb_l82lslue.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch05_wells_64kb.mp3","size":4925504,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch08_wells_64kb_82spzg6p.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch08_wells_64kb.mp3","size":3312128,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch10_wells_64kb_bgv3f8n0.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch10_wells_64kb.mp3","size":6806528,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch07_wells_64kb_n1offnbh.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch07_wells_64kb.mp3","size":4267136,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch09_wells_64kb_eohkknbi.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch09_wells_64kb.mp3","size":6283328,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch07_wells_64kb_1y6ndhqm.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch07_wells_64kb.mp3","size":16417280,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch11_wells_64kb_dautbgxj.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch11_wells_64kb.mp3","size":6151040,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch13_wells_64kb_aledo534.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch13_wells_64kb.mp3","size":6020288,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch14_wells_64kb_cd212pib.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch14_wells_64kb.mp3","size":11562368,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch12_wells_64kb_eibzjw6p.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch12_wells_64kb.mp3","size":11322752,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch16_wells_64kb_g51vzwxq.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch16_wells_64kb.mp3","size":13554752,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch15_wells_64kb_djp9o4ju.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch15_wells_64kb.mp3","size":9244928,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b1_ch17_wells_64kb_4otwu4rd.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b1_ch17_wells_64kb.mp3","size":10668800,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch01_wells_64kb_4pebkj4j.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch01_wells_64kb.mp3","size":8106944,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch03_wells_64kb_0lqsspkr.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch03_wells_64kb.mp3","size":6123392,"type":"audio\/mp3"},{"name":"files\/warofworlds_b2_ch02_wells_64kb_a84ehsss.mp3","usrName":"warofworlds_b2_ch02_wells_64kb.mp3","size":10636736,"type":"audio\/mp3"}]
```

Viewing the entry in my system is fine, the files are displayed correctly, as expected.  When I try to do an XML download of the contents the results are very very strange.

What I would like ideally is for the XML output to should the BookTitle, Author and then the list of files without all the rest of the size, type, name, files, slashes and " marks.

What would be the best way for me to go about this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you ever seen a question this long anywhere? My suggestion would be to make it eloquent and compact.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.  For reference, if anyone is interested, use JSON Parse to read the field data and then extract the name fields.

example:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM AudioBooks where BookTitle = 'War of the Worlds' LIMIT 1")) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$string = $row['FileLocation'];
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach($json_a as $p)
  {
echo $p[name] . '<br />';
  }

}
$result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your reply, I suggest do a `json_decode` of the field in json format to add to an array and later convert it to XML. Here are a litle example:

```
$files = json_decode($row['FileLocation'],true);
$values = array('BookTitle' => $row['BookTitle'],
                'Author' => $row['Author'],
                'FileLocation' => $files
)

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($values, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```